# How to make the ADC value more accurate?

Tags: adc

```cpp
void ADC1_Isr(void)
{
    uint32_t adcData = 0;

    if (ADC_ReadIntFlag(ADC_INT_FLAG_CS) == SET)
    {
        ADC_ClearIntFlag(ADC_INT_FLAG_CS);
        /* Read ADC Conversion value*/
        adcData = ADC_ReadConversionValue();
        /*  voltage(mV) =  adcData * (3300mV / 4095) */
        voltage = (adcData * 3300) / 4095;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Larry - Welcome :) Since you are new here, please see the site [tour] & [help] for the main site rules. You have written some code & added photos in the space where a clear, [on-topic](/help/on-topic) and reasonably-scoped *question* is needed. There is no specific & detailed question in the text you have given. Please ASAP [edit] your post to add a clear question, explain the troubleshooting you have already done and its results, explain what you are trying to achieve, include any specific error messages etc. In short: Please imagine that we know nothing and you must explain everything to us.

Comment: Do not hardcode 3300, instead use the ADC to read a precision voltage reference to compensate for the accuracy loss by an regulator that is slightly off

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us the accuracy you need, and why you believe the reading you have is not accurate.

Comment: 1024, not 1023 because each ADC reading represents a range of actual analog voltages not a single point voltage (i.e. the entire piece of a chocolate bar you sliced out, not the just where the slice ocurred). You are off by at most 1LSB instead of 0.5LSB if you think of it as the slice than if you think of it as the piece. Stare at this graph until you understand https://www.researchgate.net/figure/nput-output-relationships-for-an-ideal-3-bit-ADC_fig1_311795938

Comment: @Ferrybig And if the signal source and ADC is ratiometric you should not have voltage scaling number like 3300 at all. All you need is the fraction.

Comment: Please take the time to **write your question** in addition to merely plopping in code and a photo. Davide aside, time spent answering your question is reciprocal for time spent forming it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve an ADC in these ways:

Accuracy:

- Replace the present voltage reference with one with a lower tolerance
- Alternatively, calibrate the present voltage reference by measuring its actual value with a more accurate measurement system, then correct the readings in software
- Maintain the temperature of the reference constant with a oven / cooler
- Buffer the input signal with a buffer with a low output impedance to avoid the droop that occurs in many A/D converters as the signal is sampled

Resolution:

- Add dithering and averaging; that is, add a known source of noise to the signal being measured with an amplitude of 2 LSBs; then take many readings (such as 16) and average the result; that will add one or even two bits of resolution